# How to get the value of Jpicker (color picker) for each row in a loop

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, color-picker, jpicker

I have two questions.

1. I have a dynamic grid. In which the user clicks on AddNewRow button and it generates a new row with jpicker in it . Each row has a different id ofcourse. Now when Im saving the values of color picker for each row in a loop. I am using this syntax

   ```
   $('#tblCUS tbody tr').each(function () {
   color = '#' + $.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('ahex');
   Grid+= color + "♥";
   ```

Which only gives me the value of the first row. and for each loop it is giving me the value of the first picker. How do I get the values of color picker for each row? I have made several google searches and only one syntax is available.

2. Ater saving when my page gets reloaded the color picker disappears. How do I show my color picker with the values that were saved in the database? Here is my code

```html
<DIV id=divsomeid style="WIDTH: 100%">
<TABLE class=display id=tblsometable style="WIDTH: 100%">
<THEAD>
<TR>
<TH class=Greyheader style="WIDTH: 5%">S.No</TH>

<TH class=Greyheader style="WIDTH: 35%">Color</TH>

<TH class=Greyheader>Action</TH></TR></THEAD>
<TBODY>
<TR class=GreyBorder id=tblSBPComments_3 pkid="3">
<TD class=GreyBorder>1</TD>

<TD class=GreyBorder><SPAN class=colorPicker id=clcColor1 value="#00ff00ff"></SPAN></TD>

<TD align=center class=GreyBorder> &nbsp;&nbsp; </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR></DIV>
```

page load

```
     $('#tblTable tbody tr .colorPicker').each(function (index) {
          $(this).jPicker({
              window: {
                  expandable: true,
                  position: {
                      x: 'right', // acceptable values "left", 
  "center", "right", "screenCenter", or relative px value
                      y: 'bottom' // acceptable values "top", 
     "bottom", "center", or relative px value
                  },
                  color: {
                      active: $(this).attr('value')
                  }
              }
          });

      });

  });
```

Comment: Push each row value into an array. The array indexing would be the same as the row indexing

Comment: @charlietfl how ? Can you help me  as I have made several searches and wasted almost a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your page gets load you can add **active** color for all instances of jPicker depending on the value *attribute* of span tag so that it will show correct colors . i.e :

```
$('#tblSBPComments tbody tr .colorPicker').each(function(index) {
    $(this).jPicker({
      window: {
        expandable: true
      },
      color: {
        active: $(this).attr("value") //setting active color on load
      }
    });
  })
```

Then , to save these values in string or array you can use the index of the row which is been iterated and using that get the active color i.e :

```
 var color = []; //storing value in array
 var SBPCommentsGrid = "";//or in string
 //loop though table
 $('#tblSBPComments tbody tr').each(function(index) {
      color.push('#' + $.jPicker.List[index].color.active.val('ahex') + "♥"); //push value in array here index will be 0, 1..etc
      SBPCommentsGrid += '#' + $.jPicker.List[index].color.active.val('ahex') + "♥"; 
 })
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Swati_911/w30kd5h8/7/)

Comment: Hi your code works fine while saving but for getting the values , it is not working @Swati

Comment: Are you seeing any error ? Your html structure is same as i have used in example ?

Comment: It does not give me any error but in page load the color picker is still not showing . I have added the code of my page load in my question@Swati

Comment: close window bracket before the color and add `active` inside `color: {..` like i did in my code so your updated code will look like this : https://jsfiddle.net/zwdu093p/1/

Comment: and with update code in my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/L7gq354r/

Comment: I did but still not working. @Swati

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239650/discussion-between-swati-and-unknown).